# Apartment locations in Pennsylvania?

Tags: geospatial, usa, real-estate

I'm working on a project to find apartments within 30 mins of work location. I wish to know all the apartments in Pennsylvania. Where can I get this info from.

I checked https://data.pa.gov. But couldn't find it.

Comment: https://www.corporations.pa.gov/search/corpsearch and http://www.dos.pa.gov/BusinessCharities/Pages/default.aspx may be helpful, but neither seems to give a complete list. openstreetmaps.org would be my "go to" for this sort of information. You can also contact the Commonwealth directly, but they'll probably want to charge you "reasonable fees" for the data. And, of course, there's always Google Maps/API and similar mapping services.